# Using parameter from a form as part of a "like" sql statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query like this:

```
select name,label from tablename where label like '*[form]![label search]![searchtxt]*';
```

I know the query works in the sense that if I replace the "[form]![label search}![searchtxt]" with an actual word, the query works. When I run the query as is, the data from the form doesn't go into the query so I get no rows.

How can I get the like part of the query to work with an input from a form. I realize that this will probably require some VBA in addition to SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the asterisks in. Something like:

```
select name,label from tablename where label like '*' & [form]![label search]![searchtxt] & '*';
```